# Add CSS if font does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `document.fonts.ready.then`, it is possible to change CSS if a font is loaded.

Example:

```js
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
  $("div").css("color", "blue");
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/133207/moderna_-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-family: "font";
}

div {
  font-family: "font";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Lorem ipusm</div>
```

Now my question is:
Does something like `document.fonts.NOT.ready.then` exist? Or how can I change the CSS if the font gets not loaded?

Would be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet) suggests you can check for

```
document.fonts.status == 'loading'
```

or `.check()` for specific font(s).

For errors add an event handler for `onloadingerror`

In the test snippet below, `.status` changes to loaded immediately, there's a `Failed to load resource` immediately, but neither `.ready` nor `.onloadingerror` are called at that time, instead **wait for 2 minutes** *then* you get both .ready and .onloadingerror events fire along with another GET ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error (ensure browser console is open)

This is likely just due to the url for the font - a closer match to a valid font may return quicker or a 403 may return quicker etc

```js
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
  $("div").css("color", "blue");
  $("div").text(document.fonts.status);
});

document.fonts.onloadingerror = () => {
  $("div").css("background-color", "pink");
}

$("div").text(document.fonts.status);
```

```css
@font-face {
  src: url("https://badurl.com/moderna_-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-family: "font";
}

div {
  font-family: "font";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Lorem ipusm</div>
```

Comment: Oh cool, thanks a lot! <3